# Primary Buttons issue with fresh install of eOS Hera

Tags: release-hera, mouse, install

I just downloaded the eOS iso today, booted it up, installed it, and it looks great at first. I then restart the computer and find that the system settings for primary button and natural scrolling no longer works despite the GUI clearly indicating that they've been changed.